# In Geoserver, is Max Render time for WMS adjusted according to metatile size?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

Simply put, is max render time the limit per tile or in total for any given render job?  I am trying to tune Geoserver and could not find an answer for this question in the documentation.

If I increase the metatile size, I am requesting bigger chunks of data and the total render time for a 4x4 or 8x8 metatile is naturally expected to be longer than a single tile (especially with the additional data request time factored in).  When I reduced my metatile size from 8x8 to 4x4, it seemed to cause Geoserver to bail out on some render jobs even quicker, which is not what I expected.  Does anybody have the definitive answer?

Comment: I have not check deeply, but I ran today into that mechanism and should take into account the entire metatile not the single tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same max render time is applied to any WMS request. When doing meta-tiling the internal GeoWebCache makes a single WMS request, which is subject to the max render time.
So, if you want to render larger meta-tiles, you will have to increase the max render time accordingly.

Comment: That makes sense.  I presume that the reason it was quicker to fail on 4x4 than 8x8 in my test was that it hit  a bad style or excess data sooner and had nothing to do with the meta tile size in this case.